# Is it good practice to add properties on array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array is an Object in JavaScript so Can/Should we store custom properties on it ?

When we use an array, most of the times we need to maintain the current pointer/current index for the array. I see two implementations for that:

#### Implementation 1

```
var myArray = [2, 4 ,6, 8, 10],
var myArray_top = 0;
```

#### Implementation 2

```
var myArray = [2, 4 ,6, 8, 10],
myArray.top = 0; // Notice I have added top as property of array
```

Pros of #2

1. I do not need to maintain multiple variables for each of my array.
2. Code looks more readable

Cons of #2

1. If I pass the array to a method and that method may manipulate the contents and return a new array with the contents. In that case I might lose the value of "top" outside the function.

Which of the two is more better approach ?

Comment: Adding named keys to arrays is not good practice, stick with numbered indices, or use an object.

Comment: I vote against both options, because referring to the current index as  "top"  is confusing.

Comment: @nnnnnn You may refer "top" as cur_index". Its just variable name. Idea is to ask whether it is good practice to add properties to array or not

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A contrarian view. If you have values which are intrinsically connected to the array, and you want to carry them around easily, I think it's completely acceptable, and in many cases desirable, to put them on the array as properties.

Some things to note, some of which you already have:

- If you're using `for...in` to loop over elements of the array, you'll pick up the added property, but you aren't doing that anyway, right?
- You are right to point out the issue that routines such as `slice` will return new arrays without the added property. However, it seems likely that doing something like a slice might require changing the property as well. So you could write your own slice which preserves/modifies the added property. Or, you could use self-mutating array functions such as `splice`.
- Your added property will be ignored by `JSON.stringify`.

You can think of your added property as a kind of metadata. It's natural to store metadata directly on the object, where it is always there. It seems odd to have to lug around a parallel metadata object wherever you go, or to have to wrap the array in an object just to keep metadata with it.

The designers of JS, for better or worse, implemented arrays as objects that have all the capabilities and machinery of objects, including holding arbitrary properties. Of course arrays are mainly designed to be arrays, with their own methods and automatic `length` handling. But that is no reason to deprecate their ability to also be objects with additional properties when that makes sense.

FWIW, Douglas Crockford in "JavaScript: The Good Parts" (p. 62) gives an example of adding a property to an array, although in his case it's function-valued.

Of course, you should make sure that your design is such that you really need to be carrying around these additional properties. It's another thing to worry about and manage. If they are computable, it may be advisable to compute them when needed rather than store them. If you're using them as a hacky way to pass around additional information, you may want to revisit your design.

Having said all that, there is a school of thought that arrays should be arrays. For instance, [Google coding guidelines](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) say

> Associative Arrays are not allowed... or more precisely you are not allowed to use non number indexes for arrays. If you need a map/hash use Object instead of Array in these cases because the features that you want are actually features of Object and not of Array. Array just happens to extend Object.

So at the end of the day, as others have correctly pointed out here, it boils down to style and preference.

Comment: Very well written(+1)!! Thanks I understood and accept.

Comment: I mostly agree. But `.slice()` *is* a non-mutating method: it doesn't change the original array. `.splice()` is a mutating method: it changes the array it's called on.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, tweaked my answer.

Comment: I don't think javascript was necessarily designed specifically so that Arrays could be treated like Objects, I think it's a consequence of keeping the language simple (and hurrah for that, it worked better than anyone could have dreamed). I think adding non–numeric properties to an Array is a classic anti–pattern, it seems useful at first but will quickly present more issues than it solves. All just opinion and up to the OP of course.

Answer (score 5):

Consider combining both:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.myArray = [2, 4 ,6, 8, 10];
myObj.top = 0;
```

Of course if you try to keep everyone happy, you'll satisfy no one.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with this solution. (+1)

Comment: @RobG +1 This can be an alternative answer.

Comment: Would appreciate an explanation from the down voter, especially as this is a very opinion based question. I don't care about the vote itself.

Answer (score 1):

While this is primarily opinion-based, you've more or less answered your question yourself.

The question isn't really how many variables you have, but instead where you store them. Therefore #2's 1st pro is moot. That leaves us with the arguments on both side: either a) make the code readable (which is again, a question of preference), or b) make the code function predictably.

It's rather clear from this point that you should pick predictability. Either use the first or combine the two in a single object.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript programming primitive types are things such as String, Boolean, and numeric types. Objects are "hash maps" of these stored as key/value pairs, and Arrays are lists of any type stored by index. Your second implementation confuses the line between arrays an objects by treating an array as an object. A better implementation would be to store your array as a property on that object. That code looks like:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.arrayValue = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
myObject.top = 0;
```

That makes it easy to iterate over the array values and still associate other properties as part of that object. Hope that explains well why this is a better pattern. Best of luck!

Comment: Though Arrays are just Objects with a special length property and some cool (mostly generic) inherited methods. ;-)