# Is setting properties to arrays standards compliant?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, today by accident I discovered that you can set properties to arrays, which makes sense since everything in Javascript is an object.

Furthermore, this exhibits certain interesting behaviours when combined with common array iteration methods:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arr.test = 'Test';

arr.map(el => console.log(el));

//output:
//a
//b
//c

arr.forEach(el => console.log(el));

//output:
//a
//b
//c

for(let x in arr){
  console.log(arr[x]);
}

//output:
//a
//b
//c
//Test
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? Why does `map` and `forEach` ignore the property but `for` output it? Why is it possible to set a property to an array in the first place? And is this a standards compliant practice and something that I should be doing in production?

Comment: arrays are objects with length properties and some more methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it good practice to add properties on array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895365/is-it-good-practice-to-add-properties-on-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does map and forEach ignore the property

They are array methods, designed to work on arrays, and are aware that the only "real" data in an array has a numeric property name.

> but  for output it

`for ... in` loops will loop over *all* iterable properties, and any new property is iterable by default.

> Why is it possible to set a property to an array in the first place?

As you said: Because they are objects.

> And is this a standards compliant practice

The standard says that arrays are objects … so yes.

> and something that I should be doing in production?

Generally not. It is likely to confuse people maintaining the code.

Answer (score 1):

A `for/in` loop is meant to loop over object properties. That is why you are getting the `test` property when you use it.

A `for` loop that counts is meant for Arrays, as the counter is used to get at the array indices and exclude properties (you wouldn't want to iterate over the length property when traversing an array would you?).

`.map` and `.forEach` are `Array.prototype` properties that are specifically designed to iterate the elements in the array and not all of the array's properties.