# how to access object attributes of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I recently found out that in the chrome console I was able to do something really unusual.

Here's a simple example using an array of objects.

```
g = [{age: 23}, {age:33}]; 

g.foo = "bar"; 
> (2) [{…}, {…}, foo: "bar"]
```

I think I'm able to do this because all js data structures are objects? Is there any way get access to foo:bar without knowing what it is beforehand?

```
g = g.filter(function(e){
          return e.age !== 33;
          });

> (2) [{…}]
```

Specifically I'm trying to filter an array, without losing the object attributes that I set like foo:"bar".

The filtered arrays I'm getting back do not contain the object attributes I had before.

So my question is what is the best way to get access to attributes that I set on an array object when I treat it like an object in this strange way?

Ideally I could run something(g) and get back {foo: 'bar'}, or a list of all the props that exist on this object that aren't related to the array aspect of it.

Or is this just a super hacky idea and I shouldn't do it like this in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: it's hacky. It's typically a bad idea, because iteration methods aren't going to iterate over it. You could use Object.keys() on it, but you'd also get the array indexes in the resulting array. I'd suggest avoiding this.

Comment: Yes, everything in JS is an object and in JS, to create a new property that doesn't exist, you just need to assign a value to it.

Comment: see, the reason you lose it when you filter is that filter returns a new array. Since the properties you added aren't carried over, they're lost.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for own enumerable keys of the object, even for arrays.

While own properties are possible, it is not advisable, because it could lead to lose some properties, if used with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) more about disadvantage here: [Is it good practice to add properties on array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895365/is-it-good-practice-to-add-properties-on-array-in-javascript) (still opinion-based).

```js
var g = [{ age: 23 }, { age: 33 }]; 
g.foo = "bar"; 

console.log(Object.keys(g));
console.log(JSON.stringify(g));
```

Comment: Running this on my own it doesn't work. Object.keys(g) 
(2) ["0", "1"]

Comment: Interestingly, `JSON.parse(g)` doesn't include `foo`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, it is lost with stringify.

Comment: @KevinB the problem with that is that it doesn't give back JUST Foo, so if I had multiple props it might not be trivial to get access to all of them.

Comment: Right. But what it's giving you is exactly what was asked for, :p Object.keys, gives you the keys of the object.

Comment: @davidawad if you know the length of the array (which is easily retrievable,)  you could theoretically split that result such that only the extra keys remain.

Comment: you could just filter the keys who are not convertable to an integer value.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah. But, why?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, to get only the own added properties, without indices.

Comment: But, isn't `g.foo = ...` creating a new "own" property?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, right, that was the question, how to make that property visible.

Comment: No, I'm asking you "If `g.foo = ...` creates a new "own" property, why doesn't `JSON.stringify()` keep it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159287/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score -1):

This code get all enumeral keys in your object:

```
 let g = [{age: 23}, {age:33}]; 

    g.foo = "bar"; 
    let keys = [];
    for(var x in g){
      keys.push(x);  
    }
    console.log(keys)
```

But this code get all keys( from prototype also), best way for get keys -use `Object.keys(g)`

If you want  get  all keys without prototype : use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(g)`